# iOS app using a user account, do I need a privacy policy?

Tags: ios

Submitting my app soon and saw this in the guidelines:

**17.4
Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy**

**17.5
Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected**

Sorry for posting this here, really not sure where else I can ask this but my app (a messaging app) asks users to select a username and a password and then the camera take a photograph of them to be used as a profile picture. It doesn't seem like I am really sharing personal information but I'm not sure after reading these guidelines...Do I need to include a privacy policy?

Comment: What happens to the photo? Is it only stored on the user's device? Is it stored on a server? Can other users of the app see the photos of people they're messaging?

Comment: It's stored on the server. It's their profile picture so over users' devices will download it. Yes other users can see the photo. It's a singe profile picture though.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need one. You're handling user's data - chat messages, photos at the very least

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple policy, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about your app, it sounds to me like you do need one.

17.4 implies that if you're collecting (e.g transmitting to a server) or sharing with other users that you need a privacy policy. For the photo if nothing else, *edit* I'm assuming the chat messages are stored on the server (at least temporarily) and transmitted also.

17.5 suggests any kind of registration (e.g for logging in to a server) also requires a privacy policy

*edit*
You're handling user's data - both chat messages and their profile photo, so I would interpret those rules as, *yes* you need one

Comment: Yes, chat messages are stored on a server. Seems overkill though, I'm sure I've seen similar apps that didn't include one. Guess I should add one to be safe..

Comment: I guess the point is you don't know how people might use your app, and users need to be able to find out how you're going to use the information you store. If you become the next WhatsApp, people will want to know you're not selling their messages to *whoever*

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Thanks. Now for the challenge of finding out how to write one!

Comment: There's lots of samples out there. ;-)  I'd start by looking at apps which have similar functionality and seeing what they say in their privacy policies!

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT*** : Regarding to comments on you question and my answer, you'll need one because you send the photo, and the photo can be face of the user.

Comment: But if the user takes a photo of him/her that's personal data no?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the photo, chat, and the user account, you must have a privacy policy. The minor stuff only matters if you're trying for a child rating.

A messaging app isn't going to be allowed a child rating anyway (content needs to be moderated), but let's pretend it could.

You'd have to ask the user their age in the app, and if they're underage, you'd have to use a parental gate in the app to limit access to features like uploading a photo. You simply cannot allow a minor to share a photo of themselves without parental consent.

The privacy policy can be in the store. It doesn't have to be in the app.

Comment: Thanks for these details. Very useful